# Developing a minimal kernel for Linux Mint 13.4

Tags: linux, linux-kernel

I am on a task to reduce the kernel image size to as small as possible (somewhere near 5MB) and to also remove initramfs (as I want to boot it without it's support) (It's a part of a project)

Currently, the drivers are very vaguely listed under make menuconfig and I am not sure what are the critical required drivers and which are useless.

I have removed every possible support, but I want to understand some things first,
Is there any use for Crypto Functions/Sensors in my kernel?
What are the HID drivers which govern the display/ basic devices?

I noticed that there are lots of useless protocols in the kernel and I have removed them, but before installing it I have to be sure that I have not removed something which will paralyze me.

For instance what are the exact drivers required to ensure that the Mouse, Keyboard and the display monitor do not turn off (they are all Dell products) also I obviously need SCSI disk for SATA HD.
Secondly, since it has Nvidia graphics card, which drivers are minimal requirements to continue its running?
I am working on a Dell Optiplex 740.

I have searched internet and no where are the specific driver description listed. Can someone direct me to such a page if it is available.

Comment: `make allnoconfig` then work upwards?

Comment: Yeah, but how to ensure that I do not lose anything so important that my system does not boot or is severely hampered, for instance missing the SCSI driver for Hard-disk or probably missing both Keyboard and Mouse

Comment: You can add the kernel as a separate boot option so if it doesn't work, you can reboot into a different, working kernel

Comment: What about the FS? Obviously I do not need all the file systems so which one should I use (preferably the smallest) and also how to completely disable initramfs

Comment: Just choose the ones that you need to use. If you need support for FAT32, select it, Ext4, select it etc...

Comment: What support is a must to make the kernet usable with a SATA hard disk

Comment: It depends on what filesystem you want on your SATA harddisk.

Comment: This question appears to be off-topic because it is about configuring the Linux kernel, not programming.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, after being able to successfully complete it, If anyone is looking to do something similar for them. Do this by having a stable kernel installed so you can fallback in case of kernel panic's.
This is what I did:

> 1] Use 'make localmodconfig' (use make localdefconfig if you don't want to manually select lots of stuff) to get a good initial kernel which works
>
> 2] Always compile using -jN flag where N = 2x (Number of cores) (e.g. make -j4 (for dual core))
>
> 3] Do not bother about modules/initramfs in beginning, first get the
>   kernel working and then take them out.
>
> 4] Remove only things which you know are completely useless (For
>   instance Intel, Marvel or Samsung stuff if you know you are using a
>   Dell/AMD)
>
> 5] Remove everything in the networking section except the Network
>   drivers for TCP, IPv4 and Unix Sockets(If you don't want networking,
>   DO NOT remove unix sockets, it's used internally and you would get a
>   udev mount failure)
>
> 6] Remove all the sensors/backlight's/Industrial support.
>
> 7] Remove everything in security if you don't need it (including trusted and encrypted keys).
>
> 8] The localmodconfig does a good selection for the Crypto/CRC/Hash
>   section, just keep the basic ones and remove the rest
>
> 9] The best way to force all drivers to kernel is to open the .config
>   file in gedit and just replace all '=m' to '=y' (This may sometimes
>   fail, It failed for XEN for me)
>
> 10] For compiling a lot of times use distcc and ccache. (You need to
>   know how to use them)
>
> 11] It's all about trial and error at the end but you should be able to get it below 5MB in about 5-6hours. If you do not understand something, make a note of it, do not remove it till end. (Use Google as much as possible)